# I'm using swift. I cannot pass my variable to another scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been trying to pass my variable to a another scene. Previously when I was using single view application I was able to pass my variable usingoverride func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) and had no problem. Now I'm using game with SpriteKit and I am unable to use the same function it says method does not override any method from its superclass. When I take out the override it doesn't give me any errors but it does not pass the variable. Im also using the latest Xcode version and I'm not use Main.storyboard

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
    var DestResults : GameOver = segue.destinationViewController as!GameOver

    DestResults.gameOverScore = self.score
}
```

[image]

Comment: Need more context. Give us the top few lines of the class showing its declaration. Clearly it's no longer inheriting from `UIViewController`.

Comment: import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
     and your right it doesn't have UIViewController, but isn't the UIViewController only for regular applications not games ?

Comment: if it helps this is how I'm transition to a new scene   self.scene?.paused
            let myScene = GameOver(size: self.size)
            myScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
            let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1)
            self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, I can tell that your superclass isn't a UIViewController. SKScene doesn't implement prepareForSegue, so you can't use prepareForSegue in an SKScene.

You could declare a struct outside of the class declaration. Like this.

```
struct Variables {
  static var aVariable = //Whatever you want it to equal
}
```

You could access the variable like so.

`Variables.aVariable`

You could try editing the variable right before the transition to the next scene. And then access it the next scene like above.

Comment: So what are my options of passing variables ?

Comment: Just Finished Updated It

Comment: Thank you so much :) and man I can't believe I totally forgot about structs!

Answer (score 0):

You're confused about the object hierarchy. There is *always* a view controller that presents content, whether or not it has been built automatically for you.

The hierarchy is:

UIWindow: fills the device screen, and contains a root view controller

The root view controller is a UIViewController.

The UIViewController contains a root view (UIView), which in this case is an SKView.

The SKView uses the SKScene instance as a delegate to describe what its scene should look like.

You're implementing SKScene here. You need to look at the structure of your App and traverse to the right level of the object hierarchy. Or, you need to work within the game scene, and design a 'Game Over' scene, rather than an entire 'Game Over' view controller. Segues only apply between View Controllers, not game scenes.